# Use class library to store a common dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, ikvm

I've a dll generated using ikvmc, called myJavaToNet.dll. I'm going to use it in several other .net projects. So what I think was to create a portable class library and add the .dll as reference, called JavaNetInterface. 
Then in the class library add some util classes to help the bind between java translated object and C# world. Now I would add this class library as reference in my other projects and use both generated classes and my utils. Unfortunately I can only use the classes declarated inside the class library, I've no visibility of dll classes.

Can I change the visibility of myJavaToNet.dll in some way and make it public to the projects that will use the JavaNetInterface class library?

### Solution schema:

MyProject

== JavaNetInterface

=== myJavaToNet.dll